# Errors coming after creating a new project in drools ECLIPSE IDE

Tags: ide, drools

I added drools engine plugin into eclipse Kepler IDE.I set all preferences but it's giving errors in project folder.Please respond to me as soon as possible.

This is my exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    KnowledgeBase cannot be resolved to a type
    The method readKnowledgeBase() from the type DroolsTest refers to the missing type KnowledgeBase
    StatefulKnowledgeSession cannot be resolved to a type
    KnowledgeRuntimeLogger cannot be resolved to a type
    KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory cannot be resolved

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors coming after creating a new project in drools ECLIPSE IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267760/errors-coming-after-creating-a-new-project-in-drools-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Drools jars from http://drools.jboss.org/downloads.html. Download Drools Expert (first one in the list), unzip to a folder and add the jars to the project.

Alternatively, convert the project to Maven and add drools dependencies - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools. You will probably only need drools-core to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the downloaded jar (knowledge-api-5.3.0.Final.jar) to your project. it is worked for me. please see the below image to where to add jar in your project. Hope it will be helpfull for beginners.
Thansks
[Screenshot of adding jar to drools project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywAW1.png)